# Как реализовать подключение jdbc в одном классе для всех

Tags: java, sql-server, javafx, jdbc

**Добрый день.Имеется код:**

```
 private String instanceName = "Адрес сервера";
    private String databaseName = "БД";
    private String userName = "Логин";
    private String pass = "Пароль";
    private String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://%1$s;databaseName=%2$s;user=%3$s;password=%4$s;";
    private String connectionString = String.format(connectionUrl, instanceName, databaseName, userName, pass);
    Connection con;
    {
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Как можно использовать подключение только в одном классе , а в других наследовать его. Что бы не копипастить. Что бы у каждого класса было своё подключение и при закрытии соединения в одном классе, не закрывалось в других.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DAO-класс это класс который позволяет вам работать с какой-то таблицей. Например UsersDao - позволяет работать с таблицей users (читать/записывать данные из/в таблицу)

**Вариант 1** - создавать коннекшен в каждом DAO-классе (предварительно создав класс ConnectionCreator в котором будет метод createConnect с вашим кодом)

Есть ряд минусов:

1 - придется ручками закрывать коннекшен после каждого обращения, а если где-то забудете, то коннекшены начнут копиться и ничего хорошего не произойдет

2 - операция открытия коннекшена относительно дорогая и если вам важен перформанс, то каждый раз создавать его - накладно

**Вариант 2** - тут помудренее но и пожалуй правильнее. Ваши DAO-классы не должны пользоваться объектом Connection, а должны создавать sql-запрос и передавать его и некоторый класс/метод-конвертер в другой класс отвечающий за обработку этого sql-запроса, назовем его допустим SqlExecutor.

Внутри класса SqlExecutor будет создавать Connection, на нем выполняться полученный sql-запрос, происходить конвертация ResultSet'а в какой-то объект и закрываться Connection.